# Objective C: Fetch value from dictionary

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

My "saveData" dictionary looks like this:

```
{
    Adresser =     {
        "completed_status" =         {
            finished = 4;
            total = 5;
        };
    ...
}
```

And my "dOrder" dictionary looks like this

```
{
    id = 1924;
    name = Adresser;
    order = 0;
}
```

And the snippet of code

```
NSDictionary * saveData = [self dbReadFormData:_objectID];

for (NSDictionary * dOrder in dictFormSections[@"order"]) {

    NSString * segName = dOrder[@"name"];

    NSLog(@"finished: %@", saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"finished"]);
    NSLog(@"total: %@", saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"total"]);

    NSString * vFinished = [saveData objectForKey:saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"finished"]];
    NSString * vTotal = [saveData objectForKey:saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"total"]];

    NSString * sSection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  -  %@ / %@", segName, vFinished, vTotal];
    [rx insertSegmentWithTitle:sSection atIndex:rx.numberOfSegments animated:NO];
}
```

The NSLog's return the correct values. (4 and 5) But the NSStrings are nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You print `saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"finished"]` and assign `[saveData objectForKey:saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"finished"]]` to the strings. These aren't the same. Is this a typo?

Comment: Oh I'm so stupid, Yes it was a typo. Thanks! I simply changed to NSString * vFinished = saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"finished"]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Arc676, you have :

```
NSLog(@"finished: %@", saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"finished"]);
```

and

```
NSString * vFinished = [saveData objectForKey:saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"finished"]];
```

However, they are not the same. Shouldn't ***vFinished*** be like:

```
NSString* vFinished = saveData[segName][@"completed_status"][@"finished"];
```